# How can I define a custom assertion operator in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, chai, assertion

In Cypress test, I often need to check if the text in an DOM element is equal some expected test. But since there might be some whitespaces around the text, I can't simply write:

```
cy.get('.cell')
  .should('have.text', 'Hello')
```

Instead, I have to write:

```
cy.get('.cell')
  .then($cell => $cell.text().trim())
  .should('eq', 'Hello')
```

I want to define a custom assertion operator like `have.text.trimmed`, allow me to use it like this:

```
cy.get('.cell')
  .should('have.text.trimmed', 'Hello');
```

But I can't find any document in official site about it. Would someone share some example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally, I find the way to do it. Although Cypress doesn't provide such a feature, but since Cypress uses [Chai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#JavaScript), we can just define Chai methods.

Note: it's not possible to define `have.text.trimmed`, since assertion method `text` is a Chai method. rather than a chainable method, there is no way to provide a `trimmed` after it.

But there are still two options:

1. Define a Chai method `textTrimmed`. It allows us using `.should('have.textTrimmed', 'sometext')`, which is preferred since we can define a custom assertion message and no tricky hacking on jQuery instances.
2. Define a Chai chainable method `trimmed`. It allows using `.should('have.trimmed.text', 'sometext')`, which seems to work, but the assertion is determined by the Chai method `text`, which may be confusion. It is not recommended.

### `have.textTrimmed`

This is in TypeScript:

```
chai.Assertion.addMethod('textTrimmed', function (expectedString: string) {
  const $element = this._obj;

  new chai.Assertion($element).to.be.exist;

  const actual = $element.text().trim();
  const expected = expectedString.trim();
  this.assert(
    actual === expected
    , ' Expected #{this} to have text #{exp} after trimmed, but the text was #{act} after trimmed'
    , 'expected #{this} not to have text #{exp} after trimmed'
    , expected
    , actual
  );
});
```

Put the code in `cypress/support/index.js` file to make sure running it before tests.

You may want to see the complete demo here: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-cypress-add-custom-assertion-method-textTrimmed-demo/blob/master/cypress/support/textTrimmed.ts

### File `have.trimmed.text`

```
chai.use((chai, utils) => {

  chai.Assertion.addChainableMethod("trimmed", () => {
  }, function () {
    const obj = utils.flag(this, 'object')

    const oldText = obj.text.bind(obj);
    obj.text = () => {
      return oldText().trim()
    }
  });
})
```

As I said, it's not recommended because of the tricky hack and unclear assertion message.

You can also see the complete demo here: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-cypress-custom-operator-have-trimmed-text-demo/blob/master/cypress/support/index.ts

Answer (score 6):

Currently it is not possible out of the box for Cypress. The feature request is *[Provide a "Cypress" way to access textContent (and/or innerText) - .text() command](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/630)* (#630).

But you can work around it by adding custom commands to support/commands.js and use those commands in your testscript. You will end up with this in *commands.js*:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('haveText', function (text) {
  cy.get('.cell')
  .then($cell => $cell.text().trim())
  .should('eq', text)
})
```

In the test script you will end up with:

```js
cy.haveText('Hello')
```

Instead of using the `trim()` in command.js you could also use `contains()`, this does a partial match so whitespaces are no problem (note that 'apple pie' also meets the requirements if you look for 'apple', if that is not a problem you can use `contains()`. Commands.js would look like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('haveText', function (text) {
  cy.get('.cell')
  .should('contains', text)
})
```

But what probably meets your requirements even more is using `contains()` in combination with a regular expression. You don't need any scripts in commands.js, but just in the test script you can use this:

```js
cy.contains(/^\s*Hello\s*$/))
```

The `\s*` is to match any whitespace character zero or more times.
The `^` is to start matching at the beginning of the text
The `$` is to end matching at the end of the text.

The regular expression can't be used within a `should()`, sadly enough.

Comment: Thanks. Using command is a possible way, but it's a little bit heavy for me. And using `contains` doesn't fully meet my requirement, e.g. a cell have content `Hello world`, which satisfies `.should('contains', 'Hello')`, but is not what I want

Comment: check, that was why I explained the fuzziness of the check indeed. But as far as I know you are not able to create custom assertions. I'll add another suggestion, to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I'm going to create an issue in cypress github

Comment: Updated my answer once again with an addition to the feature request. Didn't know that the feature request for Cypress already existed.

Comment: I find a way to do it, please see my answer