# Cypress cucumber test cannot see custom Chai.Assertion and causes build error

Tags: chai, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I've a NodeJS React project with tests written using Cypress and the "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor".
I added a **custom Chai Assertion** in */tests/cypress/support/index.js*:

```js
//ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842707/how-can-i-define-a-custom-assertion-operator-in-cypress
chai.Assertion.addMethod("beToday", function () {
  const dateValue = this._obj
  //new chai.Assertion(dateValue).to.be.exist
  const date = dateValue instanceof Date ? dateValue : new Date(dateValue)
  const today = new Date()
  const expected = today.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
  const isOk = date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && date.getDate() === today.getDate()

  this.assert(
    isOk
    , "expected #{act} to be today"
    , expected
    , dateValue
  );
})
```

The assertion is used in */tests/cypress/integration/Components/MyComponent/MyComponent.ts*):
[image]

It seems not to "see" the custom assertion but when I run the Cypress tests it is working fine, passing the test when the value is correct and failing with the right error otherwise:

[image]

My problem is the intellisense in VS Code that does not recognize the custom assertion and **also the `yarn build` command fails**.

[image]